# XML shape as layout background

Tags: android, android-xml

I'm wondering if that's possible to create an effect as shown at the picture below **using only 1 `Layout`**. The "Description" is a separate `TextView` and not related to the question. So basically I need a rect shape with:

- Glowing border (stroke and shadow..?)
- Middle rectangle with gradient
- Outer rectangle

[image]

Any ideas if this could be achieved using only one `Layout` and XML shape as background?

Comment: What do you mean `1 layout`?  You can have as many controls as you need in one layout.

Comment: `layer-list` containing as the first layer a ninepatch(the border) and as the second layer a simple shape with gradient(with offset the number of pixels from the ninepatch that will not be stretched). I don't know at what outer rectangle are you referring. Also, please doin't prefix your question's title with Android, the tag at the bottom is more than enough.